# Prestashop multishop script to associate product to a secondary shop

Tags: php, prestashop

I am building a custom script that needs to associate some already existing products to a second shop in a multishop scenario, with exactly the same data as the first shop (including pictures, features etc.).

I see the "associateTo" method to link the product object to the destination shop,
so basically I am doing

```
$product = new Product($id_product);
$product->associateTo($shop->id);
```

This is causing product to be linked to the shop 2 , but I have no data (like price, title, description etc.) set.

What is the correct way to clone the whole product programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is associate a product to the new shop, but You have to fill all the parameters before even if the product exists and even with that will not work well.

The correct answer is to do :

```
//types of Shop class:
const CONTEXT_SHOP = 1;
const CONTEXT_GROUP = 2;
const CONTEXT_ALL = 4;

//Call this in your code
Shop::setContext($type, $id_shop = null);
```

Then all you create after this code will be inside the shop context.